# How can i make my slack bot read all messages ( and not just app_mention) in a particular channel?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, slack-api

I'm currently creating a slack bot that reads messages from a slack channel and then parses the message.

I have successfully created this using app_mention. But the problem now is that only the messages that mention my bot are being read by the bot.

I would like my bot to read and respond to **All** messages inside a particular channel.

Current code :

```
//listen to messages
const slackEvents = createEventAdapter(slackSigningSecret);
//post messages
const slackClient = new WebClient(slackToken);

//all messages 
slackEvents.on('message', (event) => {
    console.log('This is not working. Please help!');
});

//when the bot is mentioned
slackEvents.on('app_mention', (event) => {
    console.log('This is working.);
```

My code `slackEvents.on('app_mention', (event) => ()` is working perfectly.
However, the `slackEvents.on('message', (event) => ()` is not working.

I have added all the scopes that i thought were required for this. channels:history, groups:history, but still nothing happens.

How can i make the bot listen to all the messages in a particular channel? Please help!

Comment: I've added the code and removed the screenshot. Thanks for informing me about the best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `message` event to subscribe to all the messages sent in a channel.

For this you'll need:

1. Scopes

   channels:history (public channel)

   groups:history (private channel)
2. Subscribe to the event
3. **Invite the bot to the channel**

If configured properly, you'll receive event whenever a message is posted in the channel.

Comment: Thanks for answering Suyash. This is what i'm doing. Like i mentioned, i've already added the scopes and invited the bot to that particular channel. Can you share some example code please?

Comment: Thanks Suyash. I hadn't subscribed to the event. I was just adding scopes. It works perfectly now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answer -

You can use message event to subscribe to all the messages sent in a channel.

For this you'll need:

1. Scopes
   channels:history (public channel)
   groups:history (private channel)
2. Subscribe to the event
   You need to subscribe to "message.channels" event under **Subscribe to events on behalf of users** if you want to trigger event for every message sent by any user.

Invite the bot to the channel

This worked for me.